# Looping if else complex

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

What statement if i want to make a label, but i couldn't find the best solution.

[image]

```
if(diff_alt[row[1]] < diff_alt[row[0]] == more than -50 && more than 50){
     print("anomaly grounding")
    } else if(diff_spd[row[1]] < diff_spd[row[0]] == more than -5 && more than 5){
     print("anomaly speeding")
    } else {
     print("normal")
    }
```

i need for simultaneous looping,
thanks for your help im so appreciate it!

if i have an answer for my question, i will update it

Comment: Could you please give more detail about your question or clarify to some extent? I don't understand what you mean by what statement you need to create a label.

Comment: @PaulBrink so, its like when diff_alt < -50 && 0 (in row after 1) = labelled to anomaly

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure if this is what you are looking for but supposed your file is a CSV you could something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if idx == 0:
        continue
    if (row['diff_alt'] < -50 or row['diff_alt'] > 50):
        print("anomaly grounding")
    elif (row['diff_spd'] < -5 or row['diff_spd'] > 5):
        print("anomaly speed")
    else:
        print("normal")

# Outputs:
# normal
# normal
# anomaly grounding
```

For ref: my example CSV was the following.

```
alt,spd,diff_alt,diff_spd
27800,484.00,,
27775,484.00,-25.00,0.0
27750,484.00,-25.00,0.0
27699,484.00,-51.00,0.0
```

Not sure if I read your if-statements correctly...

Comment: Cool, yeah you are right.. probably im using dataframe, so what i just need to change?

Comment: Your welcome! Since you were struggling with the basics in Python (syntax, if-conditions) and Pandas, I really recommend you getting started with some sort of tutorial for both topics. This would have helped you to deal with the problem yourself (and for future issues).

Answer (score 0):

```
conditions = [
    (df['diff_alt'] <= df['avg_alt']),
    (df['diff_alt'] > df['avg_alt']),
    (df['diff_alt'] > 37.5)
    ]

values = [1, 0, 1]

df['anomaly_alt'] = np.select(conditions, values)

df
```